# Yadcf Range Number Slider for Time

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I want to filter time data like 06:21:57 using range number slider in datatables. But i can't find a way to do it. It is only allowing integers to be shown on the slider. Does anyone know how to do it using Yadcf.

My code looks like this:

{column_number : 0 , filter_type: "range_number_slider", filter_container_id: "external_filter_container0" }

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible (unless you provide a PR for that feature)

The only possile time filtering in yadcf is using the `range_date` filtering, see [showcase sample](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/dom_bootstrap_time.html)

```
{
    column_number: 3,
    filter_type: "range_date",
    datepicker_type: 'bootstrap-datetimepicker'
    date_format: 'HH:mm'
}
```

You will have to include the [Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) plugin as well (instaed og the jquery date ui picker)

p.s

I'm the author of yadcf

Comment: I cant get it to work with the  Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker library I am still getting `g.datetimepicker is not a function`

Comment: please share a jsfiddle test page